# Асинхронный триггер

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Можно ли сделать триггер асинхронным? Для меня важно что бы работа триггера не коим образом не уменьшала скорость вставок. Т.е триггер в ответ на вставку дергает какую нибудь процедуру и вставка идёт дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, триггер асинхронным сделать нельзя.

С асинхронными триггерами было бы, наверное, крайне сложно (если вообще возможно) обеспечить атомарность транзакций.

Предположим у нас есть таблица, и мы выполняем DML-запрос в явной

```
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO [Table] (ID, Name)
VALUES (@id, @name);
COMMIT;
```

или в неявной

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (ID, Name)
VALUES (@id, @name);
```

транзакции, а на таблице есть триггер, который логгирует операцию (вообразим, что он асинхронный). Предположим, что вставка прошло быстро, а логгирование задержалось. И вот подошёл момент фиксации изменений. Что делать? Если дожидаться завершения логгирования, то асинхронность теряет смысл. А если фиксировать транзакцию, не дождавшись завершения операций в триггере, то нарушится атомарность.

Впрочем, в триггере можно *инициировать* асинхронную операцию:

1. стартовать задачу (*sp_start_job*)
2. через *Service Broker* послать (`SEND`) сообщение службе, которая что-то сделает в ответ на запрос
3. поставить в какую-либо собственную таблицу-очередь запрос, который может быть обработан отдельным асинхронным процессом

Вариант 1 инициирует асинхронную задачу в любом случае (независимо от того, будет ли транзакция фиксирована, или произойдёт её откат), 2 и 3 будут подчиняться транзакции.

Answer (score 0):

для реализации асинхронных триггеров в СУБД существует технология [CDC Change Data Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) [например MS-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server)

она позволяет асинхронно подключиться к логу БД и далее выполнять необходимые действия. Нужно учитывать, что по условиям лицензирования вендорами (MS, Oracle, IBM и пр.) запрещается самостоятельно разбирать лог транзакций БД. Только с использованием их библиотек, а эти библиотеки поставляются только в "Enterprise  Edition", а у некоторых еще и требуют покупки дополнительных моделей (в 2015 так было в Oracle, сейчас нужно проверять). Даже для использование бесплатных продуктов, что бы не нарушить лицензию вендора СУБД, вам придется выбирать опции разрешающие разбор лога транзакций.

но данная технология очень хороша и позволяет вообще снять всю нагрузку с рабочей БД (подключать можно внешний SQL сервер и обработку вести вне рабочей БД).

есть независимые поставщики подобных решений, но они все платные т.к. включают в себя лицензирование API вендоров.